# asp.net webforms: Import delimited text data

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb, oledbconnection

I am trying to build something similar to excel data import wizard as per image below.

So, instead of re-inventing the wheel, I wonder if there is driver that I can use. I looked into Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB e.g.

```
new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" +
        file.DirectoryName + "\";
        Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';"))
```

However, I do not see a way to specify "Text Qualifier" and "Start Import at Row" in that connection string. Is there a way to specify these two attributes in connection string or elsewhere?

EDIT: My questions is not how to do this in c#, I am just researching to see if this can be done with OleDb connections; and how to set "Text Qualifier" and "Start Import at Row".

[image: Excel text import wizard]

Comment: why are you trying to reinvent the wheel.. also there are plenty of ways to import / parse a .CSV file using C# .net can you show us what you have done besides the connection.

Comment: I am still just researching, and have not implemented anything. Using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB seemed like a best idea without reinventing the wheel. But just not sure if I am able to set "Text Qualifier" and "Start Import at Row"  programatically.

Comment: you can set delimiters using .Config file there is a lot of awesome examples and ways to do this online as well as on Stackoverflow I would suggest you do a google search on the following if you want Stackoverflow example `C# Stackoverflow parsing .CSV file`

Comment: We are trying to avaoid external libraries. So I guess my question is can I do this with OLDEDB connections? with Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB

Comment: you can do this with straight C# Code what external .DLL's are you talking about..? I have done this many many times using straight C# Code..

Comment: We are not only parsing CSV, we are supporting all the delimiters that excel does.

Comment: Once again .. this can be done.. perhaps you should start researching and start trying something on your own..

Comment: Yes, I understand that I can do this with c#, I was just seeing if I can do it with OleDbConnections; So that I don't have to write all the logic, for parsing, supporting various delimiters, text qualifiers, skipping header rows etc..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160734/discussion-between-socialmatrix-and-methodman).